# Special character string compare to array elements BASH

Tags: arrays, string, bash, for-loop, if-statement

Im trying to code a small markdown to DocuWiki converter myself as BASH practice,
somehow I'm getting Syntax errors while executing following Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
Heading1=($(grep -E '^\={5}\s.*\s\={5}$' ZimSyntax.txt))
VAR='====='
for i in ${Heading1[@]}; do
    if [ "${Heading1[i]}" != "${VAR}" ]
        then
            echo $i     
    fi
done
```

Error:
./converter.sh: line 21: =====: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=====")

Sample Array Data:

```
===== 
Heading
1
=====
=====
Heading
1
=====
```

ZimSyntax.txt:

```
==== Heading 2 ====  
===== Heading 1 =====  ===== Heading 1.2 =====
===== Erhing 1 =====
===== Header 1 =====
===== whatever =====
```

Comment: Try pasting your code on https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check for common bash-errors.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of `ZimSyntax.txt` ?

Comment: You need spaces around `!=`

Comment: Question is Edited, ZimSyntax example added, spaces around != did not change anything.